# Is there a writing/note-taking tool that has these features…?

Tags: software-rec, note-taking

Looking for a new writing and note-taking tool. I plan to use it for creating material for Shadowrun, and misc. creative writing. I would like it to have the following features:

Must-have features:

- Keep notes in individual "items",
  like note entries.
- Easily re-order and organize notes
- Web-based, or runs on a PC
- Print out hard-copy of notes

Really-want features:

- Searchable notes
- "Tagging" feature (like stack exchange has)
- Create a link from a note that I can click through to another note (like a wiki link)
- Outline display/easy navigation

Nice-to-have features:

- Semantic structuring (like an HTML or
  Latex document)
- Drawing/diagramming
- Map feature (thinking of Google
  Wave's map gadget)

Anyone have a favorite tool they can recommend?

(Re-posted this, couldn't figure out how to migrate it, from: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/is-there-a-writing-and-note-taking-tool-that-can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [evernote](http://www.evernote.com/).  It uploads all you notes online, and i believe on your pc.  There are plenty of extras that go along with it as well.  Give it a shot and see what you think.  It's free too!

Comment: I hate the fact that you can't arrange your notes in any particular order; there are a couple optional features from my list that aren't covered, but this seems to be the best value tool overall. Having a BB app is a small bonus that I didn't think of, also.

Answer (score 2):

**@RMorrisey,**

I think you would really get a lot out of Microsoft One Note.  It has all the features you listed above and more.
 http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/demo-what-is-onenote-HA010168634.aspx

Comment: I suspect that OneNote may be a slightly better option than EverNote; however, OneNote is $80, and EverNote is free. I forgot to mention that feature nice-to-have =)

Answer (score 0):

Try an "outliner". [Wikipedia has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outliner).

Comment: I tried a couple of these, but it seems like they only permit a rigid tree structure

Comment: Yes, that's why they are called "outliners". But WikiPad and leo allow internal links, so you can think of the tree as a "table of contents".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Wiznotes note taking software would be a help for you. It has various features that are not found in other note taking software.

Eli Cohen
Mesoraware (Wiznotes is a division of Mesoraware)